# Combined responses

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, responses

I like that the trilogy keeps questions in their own silos. However it is a little tiresome to have to switch between sites to see if there are any responses. Could the response popup or envelope, work across sites?

Or at the very least could meta show responses from the trilogy as it is a meta site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now have a global inbox (RIP envelope) that shows notifications across the entire Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a central location that tracked activity across all the sites, but I would not want that feature to be built in to each site itself (i.e. when I log in to SU, I don't want to see my SF activity, and vice versa).

I also do not want to see Meta become the central location to find that user activity. We already have user activity here as a separate site itself. Throwing in all the data from SO/SF/SU would make that incredibly confusing as well.

Comment: Do you suggest a notifyme.stackoverflow.com site?

Answer (score 1):

You can at any time use the "Notify  daily of new answers" option on each question or the "I'd like email notifications of activity on my questions and answers" option on the account page.

Comment: That will only give you emails once a day if I am not mistaken, which isn't necessarily a good idea for keeping up with things to the minute.